# Список с секциями

Tags: android, listview

Нужно создать любой список, с секциями, но чтоб данные элементы(section) не являлись элементами списка. Те есть элементы АБВГД их индексы 01234, я добавляю секции к примеру: 1 - (АБ)  2 - (ВГ) 3 - (Д), их индексы остались 01234, интересует именно реализация UI. Приложений с таким списком много, но вот решения в сети используют вставку по типу и у них общие индексы, существует ли подобное решение. Понравилась реализация Telegram, список контактов, хочется сделать аналогично.

Мне интересно решение UI: При добавлений секций к списку - не менялась индексация его элементов.

Comment: `Понравилась реализация Telegram` – а откуда Вы знаете, что там именно нужная Вам реализация? И как изменится UI в том случае, если секции будут элементами списка?

Comment: Нажимаешь на элемент(longPress), выделяется и секция с ним, но если листаешь дальше то эта же секция выделятся и с другим элементом. В Viber к примеру абсолютно такой же пример, но список сбоку, те реализация немного другая, но в UI всё 1 в 1. Только опытный сразу поймет. Вы задаете вопрос к вопросу, я постараюсь для вас пояснить. Мне интересно решение UI, где при добавлении секций - в данном списке не менялся их индекс.